# Keyed Hash Functions

Tags: hash

What are keyed hash functions?

Why are they needed? I have never used a hash function which specifies the key so not getting the significance.

The key need not be secret. Why is it so?

Comment: "The key need not be secret. Why is it so?" This is incorrect, for a keyed hash function they key needs to be secret. Private and (symmetric) secret keys always need to be secret, otherwise they would not qualify as keys.

Comment: In what context did you encounter keyed hash functions? Because they _are_ used as a vehicle in cryptographic theory to model that we only have known a standard hash function for say 20 years.

Comment: Yes, The answer helped me